# Changing an object properties then calling a function inside a custom function with javascript

Tags: javascript, zendesk, zendesk-api

Title is probably a little messy. Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a custom function that will modify an object properties, then return that object, and then call a function.

A little background on what I'm doing : Trying my best with the Zendesk API to use a web widget on my webpage. Basically this web widget is configured to be a HelpCenter on startup, which then shows a button for either live chat or email, depending on the state. The main property in question here is called 'suppress' which disables one of the widget pages (chat, email & helpCenter). And my goal is to make that custom function 'suppress' 2 of the 3 widget pages so it only shows one. Then a API func called `zE.activate()` would open up the widget.

I know this is a lot of text, let me show you the code I've got so far :

```
<script>
function setChatPopOutProps(window) {
    window.zESettings = {
        webWidget: {
            contactForm: {
                suppress: true
            },
            helpCenter: {
                suppress: true
            }
        }
    };
    return window.zESettings;
};
function chatPopOut() {
    setChatPopOutProps(window);
    zE.activate();
};
</script>
```

Now when I click on the button that has `chatPopOut()` assigned, the `zE.activate()` works since it opens up the widget, but basically the `setChatPopOutProps(window)` didn't seem to work.

I also tried the following :

- Not returning `window` or `window.zESettings`
- Putting everything under a single function by putting `zE.activate()` at the end of `zESettings` or just after the return `window` or `window.zESettings`

If you need to see the widget in action to have an idea, you can see it [right here](https://support.zendesk.com/). Click on the green button on the bottom right, type anything, and you'll see the contact form button pop up. This button changes for a chat button when a live chat agent is available.

Now I know this is something that I should normally work out with Zendesk directly, which I tried, but they told me that there's nothing that can do what I'm trying to accomplish, but I really feel like this has something to do with the way I'm doing things in javascript and not the way the API is built..

Does anyone have an idea ? I would really appreciate it.

P.S. This is my 2nd post, so I apologize in advance for mistakes I probably made in this question.

Comment: In your function chatPopOut(), var window is a empty value since it is not being passed by the function.  Shouldn't it be chatPopOut(window)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it turns out that what you are trying to accomplish just isn't possible. As the zE.settings get applied when the widget is first initialized, so there is no way to dynamically alter the widget settings without doing an action such as refreshing the page and re-initializing the widget. As far I can see from your code, I dont think you want to refresh the page everytime, and reinitialize the widget just to apply those settings that you listed above.

Comment: It is currently possible with: https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/widget/core/#updatesettings